# How to add a "modified" class for an element in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

Given this scss

```
.root {

  color: red;

  &-child {
    color: blue;

    small & {
      font-size: 80%;
    }

  }

}
```

This is the CSS I get:

```
.root {
  color: red;
}
.root-child {
  color: blue;
}
small .root-child {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

I want to style `.root-child` on `small` differently so the rule I need is:

```
small.root-child {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

(Notice no whitespace after `small`)

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [@at-root](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root) like this:

**SCSS**

```
.root {

  color: red;

  &-child {
    color: blue;

      @at-root {
        small#{&} {
             font-size: 80%;
        }
      }

  }

}
```

**Compiled:**

```
.root {
  color: red;
}
.root-child {
  color: blue;
}
small.root-child {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `@at-root` and that will remove the white space in your selector, as well as it will be a valid syntax so no issues while you try to compile.

```
.root {
  color: red;

  &-child {
    color: blue;

    @at-root small#{&} {
      font-size: 80%;
    }
  }
}
```